# How to run python code interactively from C#? (like IPython in Jupiter Notebook)

Tags: python, c#

I want to run some python code interactively from C#.
For example, one C# method should call the py script which loads a model and another method should call the py script that uses the previously loaded model for inference. So the previous python execution results need to be cached somehow, so the next script can build on that.

At the moment, I can only load and infer in the same script.
This means, every call duration = model loading time + inference time.
I would like the loading to be only once, at the beginning of the programm.

This is how the C# Code looks now:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = pythonPath;
psi.Arguments = $"\"{scriptPath}\"";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

// Start the process
using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
{
   // Pass the sentences to the Python script
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine(sentenceString);
   process.StandardInput.Flush();
   process.StandardInput.Close();

   // Read the output of the Python script
   string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

   // Do some manipulation

   process.WaitForExit();
}
```

This is how the python script looks now:

```
import sys
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
model_name = "cerebras/Cerebras-GPT-590M"
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

# THIS IS WHERE TO SPLIT INTO 2 SCRIPTS

...
for question in questions:
   #Do INFERENCE

response_string = "\n".join(responses)
print(response_string)
```